# listing the elements given by a function's output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, iterator

In the code given below, I wrote two functions. The second one applies the first function. I am trying to see if it's possible to have an iteration over the elements of the first function.

This is the code:

```
def numbers(n):
    for m in range(n):
        print(m)

def sets(n):
    r=[]
    for e in numbers(n):
      r.append([e])
    return r

sets(6)
```

The result I would like is `[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`.

I know there are other ways (not defining a function) in order to obtain all numbers from 0 to `m-1`, but for what the actual code I have developed, this relates to the issue I am trying to fix.

The error message I get is:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `numbers(n)` is not returning anything for `for` loop to iterate.

Comment: When you provide an error message, it's important to indicate the line. The best way is to provide a stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numbers` function is not doing anything with the input besides printing it. Unfortunately, printing won't have a side effect outside the function itself. You have many fixes available to you.

The most pythonic is to build a generator instead of a regular function:

```
def numbers(n):
    for m in range(n):
        yield m
```

or more simply

```
def numbers(n):
    yield from range(n)
```

It would be much less efficient, but no less valid to construct the entire iterable you want up front, as long as you return it correctly:

```
def numbers(n):
    value = []
    for m in range(n):
        value.append(m)
    return value
```

or more efficiently:

```
def numbers(n):
    value = [m for m in range(n)]
    return value
```

or trivially

```
def numbers(n):
    return range(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def numbers(n):
    #for m in range(n):
    #    print(m)
    return range(n)


def sets(n):
    r=[]
    for e in numbers(n):
      r.append([e])
    return r

print(sets(6))
```

Output:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Pythonic way of solving your problem is as follows - One liner

```
def create_list(n):
    return [[x] for x in range(n)] # Important one liner

print(create_list(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

for e in numbers(n) returned None, as you can't loop over None. It means nothing was found.This might fix the problem

```
def sets(n):
    r=[]
    for e in numbers(n) or []:    
        r.append([e])  
    return r      

print(sets(6))
```

Also, try this in the first part

```
def numbers(n):  
    return range(n)
```

Comment: Consider fixing your indentation